# How to tweak page links in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite

I have a Wordpress multisite configuration like this:

- `www.domain.com/` -> Primary site (not used)
- `www.domain.com/de-de/` -> German site
- `www.domain.com/en-us/` -> English site

However, for reasons unrelated to Wordpress, I need that the network sites have this layout:

- `www.domain.com/de-de/blog/` -> German site
- `www.domain.com/en-us/blog/` -> English site

Unfortunately, you cannot define a site as `de-de/blog` in your WP network because the forward slash is not an allowed character for a site name.

Therefore, I tried defining a reverse proxy like this on Apache:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass        "/de-de/blog/" "http://127.0.0.1/de-de/"
ProxyPassReverse "/de-de/blog/" "http://127.0.0.1/de-de/"
ProxyPass        "/en-us/blog/" "http://127.0.0.1/en-us/"
ProxyPassReverse "/en-us/blog/" "http://127.0.0.1/en-us/"
```

This seems to do the trick for site routing, but in the returned page, the internal URLs in the HTML page are `www.domain.com/de-de/`, not `www.domain.com/de-de/blog/`

How could I have WP in multisite mode use URL layout from upstream (i.e. `www.domain.com/de-de/blog/`) in the rendered HTML pages?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it changing the urls of the sites to include the `/blog/` suffix.  You cannot create the site with a slash but you can change the site URL once it is created.

Then changing the RewriteRules in .htaccess to:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/blog/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/blog/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/blog/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
```

Finally, adding some code to `wp-config.php` to properly define the `PATH_CURRENT_SITE` and `BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE` variables:

```
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', $path_current_site);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', $blog_id_current_site);
```